# What I'm doing wrong with this implementation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to Implement `ExportToPDF()` action method in my `MCV.CORE` web app.
Now obviously in my `EmployeeCategory class` I have different data types(`int`,`string`,`double`).

So, my conclusion why I'm getting error, is because data type needs to be only string type. Which is not possible in my case.

I'm not sure how to correctly implement this action method.

Errors that I'm getting is:

Cannot convert type `Test_Project_Web.Models.EmployeeCategory to string[]`

`No best type found for implicitly-typed array`

My simplified `code:`

```
EmployeeCategory.cs :
```

```
public class EmployeeCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double NetSalary { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public double GrossSalary { get; set; }



}
```

```
EmployeeCategoryController.cs :
```

```
    private ApplicationDbContext Context { get; }
 
    public EmployeeCategoryController(ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        Context = _context;
    }
 
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(this.Context.EmployeeCategories.Take(6).ToList());
    }


        [HttpPost]
        public FileResult ExportToPDF()
        {
            List<EmployeeCategory> employees = (from employee in Context.EmployeeCategories.Take(6)
                                                select new[] {

                                      employee.Id,
                                      employee.Name,
                                      employee.LastName,
                                      employee.Address,                                     
                                      employee.NetSalary,
                                      employee.GrossSalary
                                 }).ToList<EmployeeCategory>();

            

            //Building an HTML string.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Table start.
            sb.Append("<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;'>");

            //Building the Header row.
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Id</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Name</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>LastName</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>Address</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>NetSalary</th>");
            sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc'>GrossSalary</th>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");

            //Building the Data rows.
            for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
            {
                string[] employee = (string[])employees[i];
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                for (int j = 0; j < employee.Length; j++)
                {
                    //Append data.
                    sb.Append("<td style='border: 1px solid #ccc'>");
                    sb.Append(employee[j]);
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }



            //Table end.
            sb.Append("</table>");

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString())))
            {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
                PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
                pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(stream, pdfDocument);
                pdfDocument.Close();
                return File(byteArrayOutputStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "EmployeeList.pdf");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this error has anything to do with the data types of your `Employee` properties and has more to do with you trying to cast an `Employee` to a `string[]`:

```
string[] employee = (string[])employees[i];
```

Aside from this not being possible (using the method above) I don't think it is necessary as you can obtain the properties and their values to output them as it appears you're attempting to do in your question.

```
employees.ForEach(employee =>
{
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (var propertyInfo in employee.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        sb.Append("<td style='border: 1px solid #ccc'>");
        sb.Append(propertyInfo.GetValue(employee));
        sb.Append("</td>");
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution is fixed my `string[] employee = (string[])employees[i];` Issue. But now I'm getting an error : `No best type found for implicitly-typed array` for the : `List<EmployeeCategory> employees = (from employee in Context.EmployeeCategories.Take(6)
                                                select new[] {
     employee.Id, ...   }).ToList<EmployeeCategory>(); `

Comment: @Unity_cube You don't need project your `employees` to an array, remove the `[]` from your linq.

Comment: I did what you said, and now I'm getting an error: `IQueryable<<anonymous type: int Id, string Name, string LastName, string Address, double NetSalary, double GrossSalary>> does not contain a definition for ToList and the best extension method overload Enumerable.ToList<EmployeeCategory>(IEnumerable<EmployeeCategory>) requires a receiver of type IEnumerable<EmployeeCategory> `

Comment: @Unity_cube I suggest you do some debugging. Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yuChAG.

Comment: Thank you for the working example. But now I can't figure out how to finish implementation of exporting already saved data from data base to my action method `ExportToPDF()` .  For example if I Implement `employees.Add(new(id: 2, name: "Dave", age: 35));`  It will only get value of `employees.Add(new(id: 2, name: "Dave", age: 35));` not the whole data base.

Comment: I did some debugging and find out that    `var query = employees.AsQueryable().Take(1).Select(_ => new
{
_.Id, _.Name
}).ToList();` is `null` now question is why is `null` ? so if I remove `employees.Add(new(id: 2, name: "Dave", age: 35));` I will get `null` value so my data from database won't be displayed at all either.

Comment: `query.ForEach(employee =>
{
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (var propertyInfo in employee.GetType().GetProperties())  {
  sb.Append("<td style='border: 1px solid #ccc'>");
  sb.Append(propertyInfo.GetValue(employee));
  sb.Append("</td>");
 }sb.Append("</tr>");
});` is also `null` you can see screenshot [HERE](https://easyupload.io/pdbfv4)

Comment: @Unity_cube I'm not downloading a random image off the Internet. You'll have to use an image hosting service or something similar if you want me to look at it. That said, this is a new issue.

Comment: Sorry for that my bad. I think that I found a good image hosting provider so [HERE](https://ibb.co/xfSsZYF) is link for my `query.Foreach ...` `null` issue.

Comment: To summarize my issue again.  Action method `ExportToPDF` should export all data from database in `.pdf file`. For now, only `//Building the Header row. ` works but data from database are not shown at all which is handled by `//Building the Data rows` in this case `query.Foreach ...` is `null` for some reason.

Comment: @Unity_cube `query` has no results likely because your database query is not returning any. Again, this is unrelated to your original question. If you need help with something else, create a new question for it as per SO guidelines.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. I will post a question today. And thank you for your help.